# Peugeot 307cc key

Tags: peugeot

I have two keys for my Peugeot 307cc 06 model but the rubber on the cover has perished on both keys now and it is difficult to open the car door.

Can I just buy the appropriate new casing for the key without the electronics etc and replace?

Thanks 
MH

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Peugeot keys I have seen have casings you can replace without buying a new key, ebay is often a good market for these. Not all manufacturers are like that, some make you buy a new key and have it reprogrammed by a dealer, which is expensive.